# Javascript library for line charting with very specific demands

Tags: charts, javascript, jqplot, flot

I have read numerous topics and went(at first) with jqplot but it lacked with some essential functions which I needed even though I find it to be a very good tool.

Now I'm in the crossroads, does someone know something more suitable for my specific demands or should I start writing my own JS library for charting?

Requirements:

1. Possibility to change axes scales(x-axis, y-axis etc)
   dynamically, not just at the initializing part(currently jqplot only
   has the possibility to resetScales-boolean if I want to replot
   again, can't scale like I would like to -> ugly results);
2. Zooming into the chart(with mouse as you select desired section), keep the current view depth even after the replot(with possiblity to change x-axis), possible in the replotted diagram to zoom out again to default view;
3. Format axes values into suitable formats if wanted(jqplot had
   it);
4. IE 8+ compatible;
5. Customizable grid lines;
6. At least two Y-axes.

If possible then please don't recommend libraries which cost.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I found something called Flot. Is there anything much more capable than Flot-> http://www.flotcharts.org/?

Comment: In what way would you like Flot to be more capable?

Comment: In general, currently I see that it is a very good tool, but I'm currently looking into the details ~ learning. I'm not familiar with all capabilities. I just wondered if someone has some sort expertise on something else as well. I'm currently very happy with Flot. I will let you know if something is missing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with Flot chart. Matches my demands very well.

Answer (score 2):

[www.zingchart.com](http://www.zingchart.com) is free with a watermark and will suit the majority of your needs.

In response to your requirements:

1. Ability to modify the scaling using the API
2. Zooming in and out to the chart is possible with the mouse, and maintains proper scaling.
3. Extremely customizable axes labels and values.  http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/
4. Current versions of ZingChart are IE9+ compatible through canvas and svg, and legacy IE with VML.
5. Fully customizable grid lines of placement and style.
6. Two Y-Axis compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://d3js.org/ ?

It has tons of options and  and is fairly easy to extend if it doesn't meet your requirements 100%

Comment: "D3 supports so-called “modern” browsers, which generally means everything except IE8 and below."

I agree, it is a very nice tool. :)

Comment: You could give http://webmonarch.github.com/d34raphael/ a try or try to use https://github.com/shawnbot/aight to get IE8 up to speed, but I agree, IE8 will give you trouble.